# Fluent Validation check for null OR min max string length

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I can't find a question asking for the exact exam problem, so I'm writing my own.

I have to validate a model with several string properties. Each of them could either be `Null` or between `1` and `100` characters.

I have some other validators where I use this approach:

```
RuleFor(model => model.Name)
            .Must(name => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name.Length > minLength)
            .WithErrorCode(ErrorCodes.MinStringLength)
            .WithState(model => new
            {
                expected = minLength,
                actual = model.Name.Length
            });
```

However I also need to check for `maxLength`, which is basically duplicating the above expression, but check for `name.Length < maxLength`. Given that I have to validate more than one property this way I feel that some optimization could be done to reduce the amount of code needed for this.

One thing that I started to implement but I couldn't figure out how to make it work is :

```
RuleFor(model => model.Name)
            .Must(name => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || (name.Length > minLength || name.Length < maxLength))
            .WithErrorCode(name.Length <= minLength ? ErrorCodes.MinStringLength : ErrorCodes.MaxStringLength)
            .WithState(model => new
            {
                expected = model.Name <= minLength ? minLength : maxLength,
                actual = model.Name.Length
            });
```

The problem here is that in `.WithErrorCode(..` I don't have acces to `name` or `model`. I guess I can assign them to variables outside the `RuleFor` but I'm not sure for this particular approach.

Comment: Can you create 3 rules? 1 for NullOrEmpty, 1 for MinLength, 1 for MaxLength.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the issue - I have 4 properties that should be validated this way 4prop * 3rules = 12 rules total. If possible I would like to combine the logic so I have only 4 rules - one for each property containing all the logic.

Comment: create your own validator: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#creating-your-first-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think The NotEmpty and the Length validator is what you are wanting

`RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty().Length(1, 250);`

.NotEmpty() means cannot be null or empty

.Length(1, 250); //must be between 1 and 250 chars (inclusive)